# OWIN cannot run multiple apps in isolation using webapp.start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, attributerouting

When I try and start two apps on different url's, I get problems with attribute routing middleware. If I have two similar routes in seperate apps but with different http methods web.api seems find only one of the methods.

```
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Admin.Startup>("http://localhost:1000");
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:1001");
```

How can I isolate both apps so that attribute routing don't conflict?

Comment: hmm, how does your request uri look like?

Comment: 2 seperate controllers in each app, both with a route prefix. One action ends up being the same as another action do to an override of the prefix using ~

Comment: are these 2 controllers part of same assembly? attribute routing tries to scan all controllers in the referenced assembly for finding attributed controllers/actions...also what is the issue your are seeing(404, 500 or something else) and how your controllers & request looks like..we need this addtional info to get a understanding of your problem...

Comment: The webapps are in seperate projects/assemblies. The code that starts them is in a 3rd assembly. I get 404.

Comment: if the controllers are in completely different assemblies, then there shouldn't be any problem...if the 3rd assembly is referencing the other 2 assemblies, then yeah all 3 would be probed for attributed routes...

Comment: Continuing on my previous comment...if you are unable to completely separate the assemblies and still would like your apps to work, you could create a custom `IHttpControllerTypesResolver` service and filter out the probed controller types to exclude the assembly you do not want to scan...

Comment: ah... so config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() will probe all loaded assemblies, not the current one (based on current called method)? Would be nice if you could specify the assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your last comment, an example below to filter out the assemblies:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new CustomAssembliesResolver());
```

---

```
public class CustomAssembliesResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        ICollection<Assembly> defaultProbedAssemblies = base.GetAssemblies();

        //TODO: filter out the assemblies that you do not want to be probed

        return defaultProbedAssemblies;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and @KiranChalla's answer got me going down the right path (thanks!). The problem was indeed with the assembly scanning going deeper than I wanted it to. For me I always wanted the scan to only include the assembly where the "current" `Startup` is defined, as that is the Web API project where all relevant controllers live. I created a resolver that always returns just one assembly:

```
public class SingleAssemblyResolver : IAssembliesResolver
{
    private readonly Assembly _ass;

    public SingleAssemblyResolver(Assembly ass) {
        _ass = ass;
    }

    public ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies() {
        return new[] { _ass };
    }
}
```

And told it which assembly ("this" one) when registering it in each `Startup`:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver),
    new SingleAssemblyResolver(this.GetType().Assembly));
```