# Launching 2 and more WebApps

Tags: c#, .net, mono, nancy

I want to launch 2 or more webApp. How do I do that in .NET? I am newby to C# and .NET.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              launchService("localhost:4234");
              launchService("localhost:4265");
        }

        public static void launchService(Component component)
        {
              using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(component.Url()))
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Running on {0}", component.Url());
                  Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
                  Console.ReadLine();
               }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be some thing as below:

```
class Program
{
    static IDisposable app1;
    static IDisposable app2;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          launchServices("http://localhost:4234", "http://localhost:4265");
          Console.ReadLine();
          app1.Dispose();
          app2.Dispose();

    }

    public static void launchServices(string url1, string url2)
    {
          app1 = WebApp.Start<StartupApp1>(url1);
          app2 = WebApp.Start<StartupApp2>(url2);
    }
}
```

Following links may help you further:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

[OWIN cannot run multiple apps in isolation using webapp.start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884646/owin-cannot-run-multiple-apps-in-isolation-using-webapp-start)

Note: There may be some compilation errors/typos in above code as I have just typed it using my IPad.